# asp.net-core - Is there a way to add an inline razor page using WebHostBuilder or TestServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get a test environment for an ASP.NET-Core middleware which modifies the request and rendering of razor pages.

Is there a way to create a simple razor page using [WebHostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Sample target code for my unit test:

```cs
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServies(services => {
        services.AddMvc();
    })
    .Configure(app => {
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseRazorPage("/some-route", "@page\n<!DOCTYPE html><html><img src=\"@Url.Content(\"~/some/image.png\")\" \></html>");
    });

var server = new TestServer(build);
// ...
```

Comment: so you want to assert on the rendered razor page (result)?

Comment: That's right, I need to ensure the rendering is correct and fail the test if it doesn't.